# The "start a bounty" popup box could not be loaded

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounties, popups

I'm attempting to start a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792088/non-linear-regression-in-c-sharp), but every time I click the "start a bounty" button, I get "Unable to load popup, please try again". I've tried refreshing the page and even logging out/in again, but none of that has worked.

Using the web developer toolbar in Firefox, I got this:

`GET https://stackoverflow.com/posts/bounty/undefined?_=1320303569613 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 446ms]`

Seems like a bug in the JavaScript.

Comment: Reproduced (Chromium 15 on Linux if that matters)

Comment: fixing it ... I made a big structure change on our question page today ...

Comment: Cheers @Mat. Just for the record, my browser is Firefox 7.0.1 (though as Mat stated it's probably browser independant)

Comment: Thanks for the quick update, @waffles. Glad to see there's such a great response speed for bugfixes! I'm about to head off to work so I'll test it again in a couple hours (long commute!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops.

Today I changed our html structure so the questions live in a node with the class `question` as opposed to the id `question`.

Clearly, it did not involve too many changes, only had to touch 70 files or so, but I missed a couple of js spots.

Just deployed a fix

Comment: Excellent. Working nicely now :)