# Loading questions from the review section is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

Each time I click "review question" in the review section, this happens:

> [image]

See that bit of the post, sticking out of the right side a bit? This seems to happen exclusively on **questions**, not answers.

(FWIW, I'm using Firefox 7.0.1 stable.)

Comment: I'm using the same browser and version and this also happens for me, that is, it happens only on http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Safari 5.1.1 running on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: same issue with same browser under Win 7. Also happens under "Review" on SU.

Comment: Hmm. Possibly related to [Padding at the top of question bodies has gone missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/padding-at-the-top-of-question-bodies-has-gone-missing).

Comment: Indeed it is; should be fixed after a refresh to get the new CSS. Can you confirm?

Comment: @balpha Yep, working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy my answer from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/padding-at-the-top-of-question-bodies-has-gone-missing/110948#110948):

Same reason as [The "start a bounty" popup box could not be loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110926/the-start-a-bounty-popup-box-could-not-be-loaded/110928#110928) – another `#question` that wasn't changed to `.question`. Fixed now, thanks.