# Padding at the top of question bodies has gone missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The padding at the top of question bodies on several sites has gone missing:

> [image: Padding on Web Applications]
>   [image: Padding on Gaming]
>   [image: Padding on Programmers]

Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, and Sketchy-based sites still seem to have the padding:

> [image: Padding on Stack Overflow]
>   [image: Padding on Meta Stack Overflow]
>   [image: Padding on Sketchy]

This is a recent change: the padding was there only a few hours ago.

Comment: See also http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/981/question-title-spacing

Comment: Also [Layout problem: gap before question too small](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/layout-problem-gap-before-question-too-small) on Meta Gaming.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same reason as [The "start a bounty" popup box could not be loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110926/the-start-a-bounty-popup-box-could-not-be-loaded/110928#110928) – another `#question` that wasn't changed to `.question`. Fixed now, thanks.